# First time creating a copy method

Tags: java, clone

I'm attempting to create a copy method, but what I have seems too simple and I think it's essentially doing nothing.

```
public Validation copy(Validation newValidation){return newValidation;}
```

so if implemented like so:

```
Validation x = new Validation(); 
Validation y = x.copy(x);
```

And then make sure that y has all the methods/variables of x and that when working with the variables in y, I don't affect the variables in x. I have a feeling what I want is a "deep copy" method and I found a post about it here: [Creating a deep copy method, Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951024/creating-a-deep-copy-method-java) but that person has no argument for their method so I don't know how it is actually copying.

Comment: Whether you need a deep copy or not, It all depends upon the code inside Vlidation class, can you provide your Validation code ?

Comment: The example in the link creates a copy of the current object (`this`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clone() vs Copy constructor- which is recommended in java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2427883/5221149).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does nothing except returning the same reference that has been passed.

Probably, you are looking for the [`Object#clone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--)* method:

```
public Validation copy(Validation newValidation) {
    return newValidation.clone();
}
```

In 95% cases, that is the most appropriate and proper solution for different types of tasks. You should not reinvent the wheel if there isn't a need of it.

As the Java documentation says:

> ... this method performs a *"shallow copy"* of this object, not a *"deep copy"* operation.
>
> ... it may be necessary to modify one or more fields of the object returned by `super.clone` before returning it.

```
Validation y = x.copy(x);
```

You shouldn't pass an `x` to a `copy` method because when you are calling this method on an `x` instance, inside the class you have an access to `this` which, in this case, represents your `x`.

```
Validation y = x.clone();
```

For a *"shallow copy"* the preceding example is good, but for a *"deep copy"* you need to override a default `Object#clone()` behaviour:

```
class A implements Cloneable {
    
    public @Override A clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return (A)super.clone(); // or or another implementation
    }
    
}

class Validation implements Cloneable {

    // an example of a reference-type field
    private A a; // with a setter

    public @Override Validation clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Validation newClone = new Validation();

        // note that the `A` class has to implement the `Cloneable`
        // and override the `clone` method making it `public`
        newClone.setA(this.a.clone());

        return newClone;
    }
    
}
```

---

*Don't forget to implement the `Cloneable` interface to allow cloning.

To read: [*Effective Java, Item 11: Override clone judiciously.*](http://jtechies.blogspot.com/2012/07/item-11-override-clone-judiciously.html)

Comment: Oh okay, so this will produce a duplicate object but whose variables have different references than the first object?

Comment: @Redcoatwright, No, instance field references will be the same as in the origin object

Comment: Josh Bloch says that [clone is broken](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html), and that you should [use a copy-constructor instead](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2427883/5221149).

Comment: @Andreas, should we use copy-constructors hierarchically for "deep copying"?

Comment: For a deep copy, you should use whatever method is available for copying of the modifiable nested objects that are part of the object composition.

Answer (score 0):

The Java api has a [Cloneable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) Interface.`Object` has a clone method that can only be accessed when it's overridden in the subclass, that also implements the Cloneable interface. Your method does not really create a copy, since the "copy" points to the original instance.

Let's say I make a copy of `Validation` :

```
Validation v = new Validation();
v.setId(1);
Validation valid = v.copy(v);
valid.setId(2);
```

Now the id in v will change as well, because `valid` points to `v`.

But the `clone`-Method makes a deep-copy. Here is a small example :

```
public class Product {

private int id;
private String name;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Product{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + '}';
}

@Override
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Product p = new Product();
    p.setId(id);
    p.setName(name);
    return p;
}   

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Product p = new Product();
    try {
        Product clone = (Product) p.clone();
        System.out.println(clone.toString());
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that might be a bit over my head. What does the "throws" do?

Comment: There is a bad example, do you realise that a cloned instance will have the same instance references as an origin one has? For a primitive `int` field, it doesn't matter as well as for a `String` due to `String` pooling. So, in this case, the standard `Object`s `clone` has the same behaviour with some optimisations.

Comment: @Redcoatwright, the `CloneNotSupportedException` is a checked exception that will be thrown when your class doesn't provide cloning (doesn't implement the `Cloneable` interface)

Comment: Josh Bloch says that [clone is broken](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html), and that you should [use a copy-constructor instead](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2427883/5221149).

Comment: @AndrewTobilko yes calling `super.clone()` in this case might have worked as well because the id is primitive and String is immutable, but if the `Product` class had another reference, let's say `Price` as field, then the clone method from the super class wouldn't work

Comment: @Redcoatwright the `CloneNotSupportedException` will only be thrown when your class does not implement the `Cloneable` Interface AND calls `super.clone()`, as long as you don't invoke it in the overridden `clone` method, you don't need to implement the Interface